# Octopress Twitter Plugin and the retired Twitter v1.0

Tags: twitter, octopress

So I'm using [Ocotopress 2](http://octopress.org/) and love it. However, I think the twitter plugin may have been broken for a while before I noticed.

I suspect it's because it uses the now [retired v1.0 twitter API](https://blog.twitter.com/2013/api-v1-retirement-final-dates).

I get

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 (Gone)`

for the URL

[`https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline...`](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/jamanifin.json?trim_user=true&count=24&include_entities=1&exclude_replies=1&callback=reqwest_0)

***Can anyone confirm that and suggest a fix?*** I can't/don't want to upgrade the Octopress 3 so I'm hoping there's an easy fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Twitter API v1.1 requires authentication so Octopress dropped it (see [the issue on Github](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1100)).

For a fix, I'm using a method described in this [pull request](https://github.com/imathis/octopress/pull/1311) which involves creating a Twitter timeline widget and adding the widget ID to _config.yml.  Easy to setup and has worked quite well for my basic needs.